# Why does Eclipse try to always add my java files to the Proj/src directory instead of the one I'm trying to add it to?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why does Eclipse try to always add my java files to the Proj/src directory instead of the one I'm trying to add it to? I mean, I get what it is trying to do, but I'd like to know how to override that behaviour.

### Edit

Here is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I have `trunk/src/acdc/ast` selected and I wish to add a java file to that folder. Yet when I try to add it, it adds it to `TTT`. (it added it first to `TTT/src` but since I've removed it from the build path it started adding it straight into `TTT`).

[image]

*(and here is how I'm trying to add the files)*

Thanks

Comment: Eclipse wants to organize things by package.  What is it you wanna do?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in Eclipse?  What exactly do you want the result to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on `src`, select `Build Path > Remove from build path`

Comment: Arghhhhhhh wait. It isn't working in other case. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: How are you trying to add the Java files?

Comment: Edited my OP with screenshots of what you've asked for.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Java perspective, your screenshot seems to indicate that your `trunk/src` folder is not a source folder for Eclipse.

Try right clicking on it and selecting `Build Path -> Use as Source Folder`

Comment: Yes, you were right. I had to make sure all my folders were considered as source folders. But now I have a problem. I cannot have branches and the trunk in the main project, otherwise it'll mix all of them when showing my code code organized by packages. Am I right? How to overcome that?

Comment: Maybe you should have a project per branch, and a project for the trunk. However I am not sure about this - and I am interested in the answer :)

Comment: That seems like a good idea. Strangely, I hadn't thought of it.